# html layout issue : how to achieve this layout?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I have three column layout. In the third column I have two divs. First div is fixed. Second div is having minimum height of 50px. when the text content inside second div increases then its height should increase to a point where it reaches the bottom of third column and then it should show scrollbars.

So far I have applied my effort here:http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Ata/1/

I have tried to achieve this layout but when I add more text inside then the main table's height also inceases. This issue can be found in this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Ata/2/

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="column">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="column">Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="table-cell">Header</div>
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="abc">
                        text content here ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.table {display:table;width:100%;height:200px;max-height:200px;table-layout:fixed}
.table-cell{display:table-cell;padding:10px;vertical-align:top}
.column{border:1px solid #000;height:100%}
.container{display:table;width:100%}
.header, .content{display:table-row}
{display:table-row}
.container .table-cell{border:1px solid #F00}
.abc{min-height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #000;height:auto;overflow-y:auto}
```

Comment: Tried using `overflow: auto`?

Comment: yes I tried that too. It is table layout issue.

Comment: I don't understand why you create table-like structure (`display: table;` and other `table-` displays) instead of using table itself? Also: if that layout will be used with constant amount of columns you could use `block` and `inline-block` displays with percent width for each column.

Comment: yeah ... I can use display:block or display:inline-block. But then I don't like the idea of clearing float. Anyways ... I think the same problem will arise in that approach as well. Any non table solution is also acceptable.

Comment: There's no need of creating floating divs if you use `inline-block`. That works like `<img>`. They are 'blocks' but displayed in horizontal not vertical lines.

Comment: @Silveraven - I agree

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `max-height` on your element in order to have the `overflow: auto` working and you will have scroll bars when the maximum height has been reached.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Ata/4/

Comment: Really thanks for a quick response. My page will be displayed in various screen resolutions and I do not want to write javascript to calculate max-height. Neither I can use media query because in that case vertical window resize will not have smooth effect.

Comment: `max-height` is a CSS property and has nothing to do with JavaScript.  This solution works, it does not require media queries, so I don't understand the objections.

Comment: I know `max-height` is a css property. But how do I know what max-height value should I apply on various screen sizes? Don't I need javascript for that?

Comment: There is `max-height` in your code. Do you use javascript to calculate it?

Comment: You will need to use javascript to calculate the 'max-height' if you don't know the content in the 'header' part of your 3th table